# Build solution fails because of linker errors on newly added projects

Tags: c, visual-studio-2015, linker

I have a solution in VS 2015 which makes use of multiple similar projects.
I added two new ones from a provided template and now building the entire solution shows two linker errors on those two projects.

I have compared configuration with other similar projects within the solution and everything was exactly the same. Building the projects one by one is successful.

At the Linker properties-> Input-> Additional dependencies I have the following libraries, created from other projects within the solution:

> CommonLib.lib;UsermodeLibrary.lib

And the linker error I get is either:

> Error LNK1181 cannot open input file 'CommonLib.lib'  ProjectName

Or:

> Error LNK1181 cannot open input file 'UsermodeLibrary.lib'    ProjectName

I put the projects in the same folder as the others, and the solution makes use of filters.

Comment: Have you checked that the linker actually searches the directory where the .lib files are? Try setting the 'Additional dependencies' paths to absolute paths of the libs are for the time being. If that works, the path you specified is just wrong, i.e. your .lib files aren't actually in the root folder of the project.

Comment: Also, in VC++ Directories -> Library Directories, you can set the FOLDERS where the linker searches for the libraries, AFAIK. ALSO, check if the settings are set for the configuration you're actually trying to build.

Comment: Thank you for the tips! The settings must be very specific to the new projects because I get the errors only on the new ones I added, even though I put them in the exact same folder with the other similar projects. So far I have checked with a file diff the new and the existing project files and they have the exact same paths configured. I will check the second thing you mentioned, but I did compare that even the build options are the same before asking the question.

Comment: Each project requires specific configuration. If the paths aren't configured properly, they might contain some specific values instead of variables whose values are used.

Answer (score 1):

My lab teacher figured this out for me.
For the sake of the answer let's call the new project I added from template "MyProject".

"You have to go the properties of the solution (right click on the solution -> Properties), there you go in the left tab to *Common Properties\Project Dependencies*.
After that you choose at the middle top of your projects (ex.: MyProject) and in the bottom window, you have to search for UsermodeLibrary and check/select it as a dependency for the project.

The thing is that every project is configured **OK** in the Project Properties (linker related and the rest), the only problem is that when you are *building the solution* it has to know per solution that some projects depend on other projects. 
Here the dependency hierarchy is the following:

> MyProject -> UsermodeLibrary -> CommonLib (-> means "depends on").

That's why you are seeing that CommonLib can't be linked to the project because it is not built before those applications.

Somehow, your templates miss this setup in regard to the Solution in which they are created."